# Reading text file line by line in android app

Tags: android, file, assets

I am trying to make an android app using android studio. My app needs to read a text file line by line, and perform a task on the string on each line. I am using bufferedread for this, but I am constantly getting a File not found error. I created an assets folder in /app/src/main/assets/ and I have copied the text file into this assets folder. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Please find my code below :-

```
package com.example.spandanmadan1.hinglish;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.provider.UserDictionary;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        Button bsubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Hinglishbutton);

        bsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AssetManager assManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
                InputStream fis = assManager.open("HindiSlang.txt");
                BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

                String line=null;
                while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
                    UserDictionary.Words.addWord(getApplicationContext(),line,1,"",null);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try one of the following:

```
try {
    fIn = getApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets()
            .open("HindiSlang.txt", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        // process the line..
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
```

OR write a function:

```
public String LoadData(String inFile) {
    String tContents = "";

  try {
     InputStream stream = getAssets().open(inFile); // you will get the method getAssets anywhere from current activity.

     int size = stream.available();
     byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
     stream.read(buffer);
     stream.close();
     tContents = new String(buffer);
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // Handle exceptions here
   }

   return tContents;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I made it work by storing the file in the /res/raw/ directory and using getResoruces().

Comment: you should use Context.MODE_PRIVATE instead of Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Kotlin example for reading an InputStream (or File) line-by-line:

```
InputStream.bufferedReader().useLines { lines ->
  lines.forEach { line ->
    System.out.println(line)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In **Kotlin**, I used this way for simple text such as Titles:

```
val fileName = "list100.txt"
val inputString = application.assets.open(fileName).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
val list100: List<String> = inputString.split("\n")
```

Don't forget add your file in the **Assets** folder!